# Extension method for methods do not show in IntelliSense

Tags: c#, .net, function, extension-methods, timing

How do I create an extension method that can execute a given function later? I've come up with the following code, but it doesn't list in the IntelliSense list when you type `MyFunc.DoLater()`.

I've declared the extension method in a static class...

```
using TTimer = System.Timers.Timer; // to prevent confusion with Windows.Forms.Timer

public static void DoLater(this Action handler, int delay) {
    TTimer timer = new TTimer(delay);
    timer.Elapsed += delegate {
       handler();
       timer.Dispose();
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

... and `MyFunc` is just a method in a `Form` class with no parameters.

```
public void MyFunc(){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the method as an `Action`.

```
((Action)MyMethod).DoLater(10000);
```

To use the extension method, the compiler is expecting an object of type `Action`.  I'm not entirely sure what the difference between a method member and an `Action` member is, but I'm guessing there's an explicit conversion from method to `Action`.

Answer (score 3):

You need an action instance to execute your extension method on:

```
var a = new Action(() => MyFunc());
a.DoLater();
```

But I would suggest a better and more generic approach:

```
public static class DoLaterExtension
{
    public static void DoLater<T>(this T x, int delay, Action<T> action)
    {
        // TODO: Impelement timer logic
        action.Invoke(x);
    }
}

private void Example()
{
    var instance = new MyForm();
    instance.DoLater(1000, x => x.MyFunc());
}
```

Keep in mind that you should better use a `System.Windows.Fomrs.Timer` to avoid thread issues.
Or the TPL way (if you are on .net 4.0 i would suggest that).

```
public static void DoLater<T>(this T x, int delay, Action<T> action)
{
    var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);   
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        action.Invoke(x);
    }, scheduler);
}
```

And if you use .net 4.5 you can even use `Task.Delay` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to define an extension method directly for the "method" data type (if there is one?) ... I can change the extension anyhow, but I'd like to work with "ordinary" methods if thats possible.

Comment: @Geotarget unlike in e.g. JavaScript methods are not objects in C#. The syntax makes you believe so but in reality `Action f = m.Foo` is syntactic sugar for the creation of a delegate that's then assigned to f. You will need to create an object, again which a method is not, before you can invoke an extension method

Comment: This syntax .. `((Action)MyMethod).DoLater(10000);` is much better and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea. I tried it using System.Timers.Timer and it works fine.

```
static class Program
{
    static System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoLater(SayHello, 5000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DoLater(this Action handler, int delay)
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(delay);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(delegate {
                                   handler();
                                   _timer.Dispose();
                                });
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public static void SayHello()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've corrected my question to update that. When I checked it my code it was already `System.Timers.Timer` but when I rewrote it in SO I got it wrong. Thanks again, but I knew this. I'm just trying to make the "extension method" feature work, as in call this method as an extension method... like `SayHello.DoLater()`

Comment: cool! let me know what you come up with, i thinks its a very interesting idea!

Comment: This syntax .. `((Action)MyMethod).DoLater(10000);` is much better and it works!